# Querying the ASP.NET form object with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Is it possible to select all controls that inherit a particular abstract class with linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the [`Enumerable.OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb360913) extension method:

```
...Form.Controls.OfType<MyControlBase>()...
```

To perform this recursively see the [other answer](http://#828666): create an iterator that walks the control tree to create a list which you then apply LINQ operators to.

Comment: I guess the controls I'm looking for are nested in another. When I try this it returns nothing.

Comment: Yes you'd have to recursively descend through the controls collection gathering them up as you go.

Comment: So why use linq if you have to iterate with loops?

Comment: @Slim: Because it gives you some seriously powerful filtering and processing capabilities, once one reusable loop is written.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a method which recursively gets all the controls, as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetControls(Control form) {
    foreach (Control childControl in form.Controls) {   // Recurse child controls.
        foreach (Control grandChild in GetControls(childControl)) {
            yield return grandChild;
        }
        yield return childControl;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var controls = GetControls(form).OfType<SomeControlBase>();
```